# Sharepoint Date Time Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, calculated-columns

I have 2 columns sDate ( Start Date ), eDate ( End Date ) in my list.
The functionality I need

```
if(eDate == "" )
 print sDate // Nov 10
else if(MONTH(sDate) == MONTH(eDate))
 print sDate("mmm dd") + eDate(" - dd")  // Nov 10 - 17
else
 print sDate("mmm dd") + eDate(" - mmm dd") // Nov 10 - Dec 10
```

Orignal:

```
=IF(eDate="",TEXT(sDate,"mmm dd"),CONCATENATE(TEXT(sDate,"mmm dd")," ",(TEXT(eDate,"- dd"))))
```

I tried:

```
=IF(eDate="",TEXT(sDate,"mmm dd"),(IF(MONTH(sDate)=MONTH(eDate),CONCATENATE (TEXT(sDate,"mmm dd"), " ", TEXT(eDate,"- dd")),CONCATENATE (TEXT(sDate,"mmm dd"), " ", TEXT(eDate,"- mmm dd"))))
```

I get this exception, which is not very helpful:

> The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.UpdateField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrXML)
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.UpdateField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrXML)

Comment: Not directly answering your question but you may find this useful - http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/05/sharepoint-calculated-column-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add one more closing parenthesis `)` at the end of the expression.

**Excel is useful to debug SharePoint calculated column expressions** - I have pasted your expression into Excel spreadsheet, replaced `sDate` and `eDate` with addresses of cells containing example dates and **Excel suggested a correction automatically**.

Comment: You can also use a programmers editor like Notepad ++, it will highlight matching pairs of opening/closing parenthesis.

Comment: @Marek - thanks for letting me know about the missing `)` . I was pulling out my hairs to find a problem in expression.

Comment: @Ryan: A big advantage of Excel in this scenario is the fact that it can evaluate SharePoint expressions.